# Cannot set width or height to webgrid columns and rows

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to regulate the size of the rows in a webgrid subtable, with no success. The following is the start of my table's creation script:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
            htmlAttributes: new { id = "gridT", width = "700px" },
            tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
            columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("singleUser.RA_Responsible_Person", "RA Responsible Person"),
                    grid.Column("singleUser.Issues_Count", "Issues Count"),
                    grid.Column(header: "Min Deadline", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", item.singleUser.Min_Deadline)),
                    grid.Column(header: "Max Deadline", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", item.singleUser.Max_Deadline)),

                    grid.Column(format: (item) =>
                    {
                        WebGrid subGrid = new WebGrid(source: item.Cases, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5);
                        return subGrid.GetHtml(
                            htmlAttributes: new { id = "subT" },
                            columns: subGrid.Columns(
                                    subGrid.Column("Issue_ID", "Issue_ID"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Issue", "Issue"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Case_Status", "Case_Status"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Issued_by", "Issued_by"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Issue_Date", "Issue_Date"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Issue_Type", "Issue_Type"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Server_Name", "Server_Name"),
                                    subGrid.Column("DB_Name", "DB_Name"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Issue_Desciption", "Issue_Desciption", style: "longTextColumn"),
                                    subGrid.Column("RA_Responsible_Person", "RA_Responsible_Person"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Reasons_For_Issue", "Reasons_For_Issue", style: "longTextColumn"),...
```

I assign some of the columns into the class "longTextColumn", which should be wider:

```
.longTextColumn {
    max-height: 60px;
    width: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then, I assign max-height to every row in the main table, because I need the information to fit in smaller space.

```
    #gridT tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #eee;
        max-height: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #gridT tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #fff;
        max-height: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Of course, these things don't work, because size definition doesn't work on single columns anymore. I used to solve the issue by nesting divs inside the cell, but with this code idk how and I don't want to do it this way. Can anyone give me an advice?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I tried to assign fixed width to my whole table - it doesn't help.
I know that I assign conflicting max-height, but none of them affect the rows, so it doesn't matter. Plus I did one of the styles before the other and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to override style with !important in your css?

Comment: It would be of no point. I can see my declarations in the browser. They are active (not crossed). They just don't take effect. I know this problem, because I encountered it once. But the solution then cannot be applied.

How can I explicitly set width and height of a single table column or row?

Comment: In theory you can intercept after rendering and give a different css attribute to the row. I've done something like this with Telerik ajax .net grid controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I've resorted to my old and tested solution - I hacked by wrapping a div around the td cell. Very ineffective and unnecessary. I hope someday the good folks will once again bet on our intelligence and allow us to set size on our own columns.

Here is the solution:

Added a class:

```
                        columns: subGrid.Columns(
                                    subGrid.Column("Issue_ID", "Issue_ID"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Issue", "Issue", style: "long"), .....
```

and a script:

```
    <script>
        $(".long").each(function () {
            $(this).wrapInner("<div class='longTextColumn'></div>");
        });
    </script>
```